# ActionMailer email sending on development but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

My production settings on heroku are this:

```
# ActionMailer Config
  # Setup for production - deliveries, no errors raised
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :safety_mailer
  config.action_mailer.safety_mailer_settings = {
    allowed_matchers: [/\+send@blueapron.com/, /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){5,}@blueapron.com$/, /blueapron.runme@previews.emailonacid.com/],
    delivery_method: :smtp,
    delivery_method_settings: {
      address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      port: '587',
      authentication: :plain,
      user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      domain: AppConfigs[:application][:email_domain]
    }
  }
end
```

And this works when I try to send an email locally. At least, it works in the sense that deliver! opens up a webpage with a webpage representation of my email.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

The command I'm running to send my email is this:

`UserMailer.confirm_email.deliver!`

Comment: make sure in your your production server you have open firewall port 25 for smtp (sudo ufw allow 25)

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: usually in production server (cloud server) they have firewall to protect ports, and email is using port number 25 (smtp), and usually the default setting is disabled.

Comment: Im on heroku, any ideas on how to check this?

Comment: probably you can test it first here is link how to http://blog.industrialnetworking.com/2011/09/using-telnet-to-test-open-ports.html

Comment: dont I have port 587 specified here?